# Como tratar requisição POST no laravel que foram enviandos como parâmetros?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

Definir um rota dessa maneira na API:

```
$this->router->post('/logo', 'MinhaContaLogoController@adicionarLogo')
```

Porém a requisição do meu Client envia um parâmetro na URL em method POST:

```
/logo?fileapi154288602223716
```

como essa rota não existe o retorno é 404 Not Found

Comment: Não. O Laravel não considera o `?` na rota. O problema pode ser que ele está enviando uma requisição `GET` numa rota `POST`. O retorno disso é 405 (método não aceito)

Comment: Entendi! Só que não conseguir tratar essa requisição nem como  GET  e nem     POST, como não consigo tratar - la a reposta que tenho é 404 Not Found.

Comment: testa aí. Manda um post via POSTMAN. Pode ser muita coisa o problema, inclusive na configuração do Apache (se estiver usandoO)

Comment: Coloque todo o seu controler, coloque todo o arquivo de rota ... no minimo está errado o jeito que você está fazendo